# java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception Error when Deploying Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have this applet that I am trying to deploy in a html file, and when it does it gives me the error of `java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception` and I have no idea why. (This is for my Java Programming class)

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
/* This program is meant to track how many times the user clicks btnNewButton and displays it in a JLabel.
 * The clicks can also be reset with the reset button, moving the clicker back to 0 */

public class MouseClicks extends JFrame {
    // Makes sure frame is shown
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MouseClicks frame = new MouseClicks();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public MouseClicks() {
    // Sets size of frame to 420 x 200, is resizeable though
        setSize(420,200);

    /* Displays instructions for user
     * Used HTML to make the instructions red in order to popout to the user more */
        textPane = new JLabel("<html><p><u><b>Instructions:</b></u></p><p><font color=\"red\">Click the button below for clicks to be counted and displayed,</font></p><p><font color=\"red\">press the Reset Clicks button to return click counter to 0.</font></p></html>");

        // Makes font SansSerif, plain, and size 15pt
        textPane.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        getContentPane().add(textPane);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Click Here to count Mouse Clicks!");
        btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override           
            // Tracks clicks of mouse
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // Increases clicks everytime button is clicked
                clicks++;
            // When button is clicked, the counter is displayed on the Counter JLabel
                Counter.setText(header +clicks);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        // Resets clicks back to 0
        JButton btnResetClicks = new JButton("Reset Clicks");
        btnResetClicks.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent c) {
                clicks = 0;
                Counter.setText(header +"0");
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btnResetClicks);


        Counter = new JLabel();
        getContentPane().add(Counter);

        // Makes layout flow, not a strict place where every component is
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    }
       // Static Label for # of clicks
       private static String header = "Clicks: ";

       // Sets default amount of clicks to 0
       private int clicks = 0;
       private JLabel Counter;
       private JLabel textPane;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `MouseClicks` class needs to extend Applet or JApplet (in this case, since you are using Swing, you should use JApplet).

So change this:

```
public class MouseClicks extends JFrame {
```

to

```
public class MouseClicks extends JApplet {
```

and add `import javax.swing.JApplet;` to the rest of the imports at the top of your file.

See here for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html

Comment: The stuff in the constructor should also be in an `init()` method of an applet.  But to the OP:  1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) The best way to deploy a Java desktop application (e.g. `JFrame`) to the web is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).